# Websphere profile path already exists during node creation

Tags: websphere, was

When I try to federate Websphere node with Deployment Manager i get error during creation:

```
<record>
  <date>2020-05-15T08:24:01</date>
  <millis>1589523841283</millis>
  <sequence>438</sequence>
  <logger>com.ibm.ws.profile.validators.DirectoryValidator</logger>
  <level>SEVERE</level>
  <class>com.ibm.ws.profile.validators.DirectoryValidator</class>
  <method>isValidDir</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>The -profilePath '/opt/IBM/WAS8/profiles/AppSrv01' already exists, and is not empty</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2020-05-15T08:24:01</date>
  <millis>1589523841286</millis>
  <sequence>439</sequence>
  <logger>com.ibm.ws.profile.validators.DirectoryValidator</logger>
  <level>SEVERE</level>
  <class>com.ibm.ws.profile.validators.DirectoryValidator</class>
  <method>runValidator</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>The profile path is not valid.</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2020-05-15T08:24:01</date>
  <millis>1589523841286</millis>
  <sequence>440</sequence>
  <logger>com.ibm.wsspi.profile.validators.GenericValidator</logger>
  <level>SEVERE</level>
  <class>com.ibm.wsspi.profile.validators.GenericValidator</class>
  <method>getErrorOutput</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Returning error message:The profile path is not valid.</message>
</record>
```

Command to create profile:

```
/opt/IBM/WAS8/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName AppSrv01 -profilePath /opt/IBM/WAS8/profiles/AppSrv01 -templatePath /opt/IBM/WAS8/profileTemplates/managed -dmgrHost dmgrhost  -dmgrPort 8879 -dmgrAdminUserName myuser -dmgrAdminPassword 'mypassword' -federateLater false -hostName mynodehostname
```

This node is fresh and I'm pretty sure the folder is empty before command execution.

Comment: First check if you have anything in `/opt/IBM/WAS8/profiles/AppSrv01` and your user can actually access it and create folder there. Second run ./manageProfiles.sh -listProfiles to check if you dont have some old invalid profiles. My guess is that you already have AppSrv01 profile.

Comment: @Gas there is nothing in the profile. This is a fresh installation on a new host.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Remove temp and cache using cleanCache.sh and osgi located in bin
folder.  Then run again the profile tool.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you install again dmgr.

**/!\ be careful.**

So Clean up :

```bash
/opt/IBM/WAS8/AppServer/bin/manageprofiles.sh -deleteAll
rm -Rf /opt/IBM/WAS8/AppServer/profiles/*
```

Then install again dmgr then AppServer